# PHP array being passed to javascript function not doing anything

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php array that is being passed to a js function using "json_encode($array)", the problem is that when I click the button to trigger the function, nothing happens besides the page refreshing.

I think the problem might be the enclosing quotes, though I already tried changing from double to single and vice verse, no joy.

HTML:

```
 <button class="button1" 
  onclick="validateEncomenda('<?php echo json_encode($chosen_restaurant_addr);?>');
           return false;">Encomendar</button>
```

js:

```
function validateEncomenda(myarray){
   alert('Hello JS');
  }
```

if I echo the "json_encode($chosen_restaurant_addr)" 
I'm getting the right values in this format:

["ipsum lorem blah blah","Curabitur aliquam feugiat tellus"]

Any help or hint will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the array you want to encode to json.

Comment: Your double quotes in the json are closing the onclick event attribute. `onclick="validateEncomenda('["`

Comment: Right, it seems to be a enclosing quotes problem. Can you post the computed value of `json_encode($chosen_restaurant_addr)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the quotes in the PHP output. Since HTML quote can't be escaped, rewrite it like this :

```
onclick='validateEncomenda("<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($chosen_restaurant_addr)); ?>"); return false;'>
```

Comment: This works if i remove the "return false;" with the return false it tell me "invalid return" as a syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

A better way to handle this would be to separate the onclick handling out from the HTML source.  You could create a script like this:

```
var chosenResturant = <?php echo json_encode($chosen_restaurant_addr);?>;
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
    // no need to parse JSON here as we created an array literal above
    alert(chosenRestaurant.length);
    return false;
};
```

Note here that I am assuming that you add an id `button1` to the element as the means for determining which elements gets the event handler. If you truly want to attach this behavior to all elements with the class name of `button1`, you would simply substitute `getElementsByClassName('button1')` instead of `getElementById('button1')`

Comment: You're missing quotes around the json ;)

Comment: @blue112 I don't need quotes around it.  I am defining an array literal (as I noted in my code sample).

Comment: Oh yeah, it's json, it's working out of box in js, of course, my bad.

Comment: Right the only problem is that i have all my JS in a separate file, and I'm using a function because for this case it works best as i have many other functions being called inside the validateEncomenda() function.

Comment: @MichelFigueiredo You could still have the onclick handler function definition in a static js file and define the variable dynamically via PHP inside script tags (in essence what you are doing in the inline function call now).

Comment: Thanks I know that,but for some cases I prefer using functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add new attribute for the button: type="button"